# Uninstalling Anaconda - failed to run pre_uninstall

Tags: anaconda, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall Anaconda from a Windows system by running 'uninstall' via Settings/Apps/Installed apps. The Uninstall wizard opens but after confirming the uninstall, fails with the notice "Failed to run pre_uninstall" (although there is a (empty) pre_uninstall.bat file in the folder).

After ignoring the error notices "Failed to run rmpath" and "Failed to run rmreg" appear. The uninstall completes but unsuccessfully.

Trying to uninstall Anaconda via settings/apps/uninstall. Expected to remove all of Anaconda from the system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.